# Set form-control to the same size as form-control-sm in boostrap 4

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I would like to override bootstap so that `form-control` is the same size as `form-control-sm`.

I've got a bootstrap-custom.scss file and found the following in [_forms.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss)

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: $input-height-base; // Make inputs at least the height of their button counterpart (base line-height + padding + border)
  padding: $padding-base-vertical $padding-base-horizontal;
  font-size: $font-size-base;
  line-height: $line-height-base;
```

I tried adding the following but it didn't work:

```
$padding-base-vertical:     5px !default;
$padding-base-horizontal:   10px !default;
```

Comment: to override defaults without rebuilding Bootstrap 4, should just be a matter of loading your override css file after the bootstrap css and using `!important` when applicable on your overrides styles

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4? the `_forms.scss` you referenced is old from 3.x

Comment: @Zim yes I'm using 4 so that might explain part of my problem - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the appropriate SASS variables from Bootstrap 4...

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$input-padding-y: $input-padding-y-sm;
$input-padding-x: $input-padding-x-sm;
$input-height: $input-height-sm;
$input-font-size: $input-font-size-sm;

@import "bootstrap";
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/mHAz7ecNiy